# Can I bring the content from parent provisional application to a continuation?

Tags: continuation, continuation-in-part, amendment

Let's just say,

I filed a Provisional Application in Jan 2019.

I filed a non-provisional in Dec 2019 by claiming priority to the Provisional, properly. But I missed some content in non-provisional that are available in the Provisional.

(1) Can I bring the missed Provisional content to non-provisional by filing amendments? If yes, Is there any deadline? Is there any additional fees I have to pay in USPTO?

(2) If I file a continuation with the missed content, will that be considered as continuation or continuation-in-part (CIP)?

Thanks

Comment: Besides properly claiming priority did you by ant chance also "incorporate by reference"?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Yes I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the provisional was incorporated by reference, you can amend in any material from it that you like. And a continuation that only has material from the provisional + the parent will not need to be a CIP. Make sure to also properly claim the benefit of the provisional in the continuation.

Comment: Thanks Mr. White. You are very helpful.. as usual. Have a nice day :-)

Comment: Can I also amend the claims to protect the content brought from the provisional?

Comment: Claims needed to be supported by the disclosure. So, yes, if the specification is expanded there may be claims that could be added or expanded.